# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xmbeans.XmlBeans

Tags: java, linux, weblogic, xmlbeans

I am trying to submit Excel with million of data,I have following jars in my classpath

```
poi-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-3.9.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
```

It is working fine in my local machine. But when I try to run it on linux and it published in weblogic it gives me the following **error**:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.xml.namespace.QName`

when  try it  again it gives me the following **error**:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans`

Answer (score 0):

Are you publishing a .war or similar in your local machine or running it from your IDE?

You could be getting the NoClassDefFoundError because you are not including your libraries in your .war. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992060/eclipse-including-libraries-with-war-file-project?rq=1)

Comment: I use OSGI it has more than 100 bundles,I don't know why the first error is'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.xml.namespace.QName' After that is “java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans”

Comment: if I pulishing it in my local machine it will be very troublesome .

Comment: Just make sure you are including j2ee.jar (or any other jar that includes the class you are missing) in your .war. Check this jar is either in your WebContent folder or if it is an external lib, you are exporting it.

Comment: think you very much