# best practice for invoking a Java Swing program

Tags: java, swing, bash

When not running the IDE (Eclipse for Java), I invoke my Swing app via a bash script on ubuntu.  The script contains a lengthy classpath option.

Is there a better way considered to be a best practice?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar . You can distribute your application as executable jar.

Answer (score 3):

You should create an executable jar-file with your classes. Then you can run your application with `java -jar yourApp.jar` or by double clicking it.

In Eclipse you can create a jar-file by exporting your project. See also [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)

Comment: +1 This is true of any java program that you need to launch, it not specific to swing.

Answer (score 1):

There is also [Java Web Start](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/index.html). You could deliver your application via the web (classpath set in the JNLP file) and then launch it via URL and/or a shortcut on your desktop. It can still run as a local application.

Answer (score 1):

Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character * since Java 6 [Setting the class path](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)