# Running Java Program From Command Line

Tags: java, command

so I am having a noob moment here, I haven't ever used the command line to run a java program before but I need to right now. The problem I am having is that when I try to run the program I get a ClassNotFoundException. My class is called OmadUpdate. I already have compiled the OmadUpdate.java file into OmadUpdate.class using the javac command. I have checked the directory and they are both definitely there, however when I run the java OmadUpdate command, it gives me an error message saying

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: OmadUpdate (wrong name:     org/openmetadata/main/OmadUpdate)
......
......
Could not find the main class: OmadUpdate. Program will exit
```

But its right there in the directory. When I type dir I have both OmadUpdate.class and OmadUpdate.java. I have even tried using "java org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate" because that is the package name that it is under. I am stumped. Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: Can you post your source code file? Are these files within the correct folder hierarchy? (i.e. is OmadUpdate.java inside a folder called "main" inside a folder called "openmetadata" inside a folder called "org"? Are you using a "package" declaration at the top of your java source file?

Comment: see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class appears to have been declared in the `org.openmetadata.main` package.

To get java to load the class correctly, it needs to be in the correct directory structure that matches the package structure.

So the classfiles for `org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate` should be in the directory `org\openmetadata\main`.

Then, when you run the `java` command, the root of this directory structure should be on the classpath - for a simple example this just means that your current directory should be the parent directory of  `org\openmetadata\main`.

When running `java` you need to specify the full classname using periods not slashes, i.e.

```
java org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone who answered so quickly, but this is the one that worked, the -cp did not seam to help, all I had to do was java org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 5):

After you compile the class with javac, you'll have the following directory structure:

```
org/
  openmetadata/
    main/
      OmadUpdate.class
      OmadUpdate.java
```

Make sure you're in the parent directory of org, then run

```
java -cp . org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate
```

Answer (score 2):

Class names have their nested package names separated by periods, while the directories use slashes.  Odds are good you tried `java -cp . org/openmetadata/main/OmadUpdate` when you should have (since you are specifying a class name) tried `java -cp . org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate`

Note that for this to work, you must run it in the directory just above the `org` subdirectory.  Otherwise that classpath directive `cp .` will start the search in the wrong directory.

Answer (score 0):

launch your java app with the classpath set:

```
java -cp . org.openmetadata.main.OmadUpdate
```

Answer (score 0):

-cp . won't do anything I don't think. You have to make sure you are invoking java in the right directory, which is the part to the first package name / folder (in your case org)

You need to use the full package and class name to run it.