# How do I run a java program in cmd?

Tags: cmd

I have created a program in Java, but it is not taking the inputs correctly in edit-plus(compiler) so now I want it to run in cmd. My JSK file is at : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin` and my Java file is at: `C:\TurboC4\TC\java new programs`

Please tell me the steps to run it in cmd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line use:

```
java -jar path/to/your/jar_file.jar
```

if you do not have a jar file, than you have to compile first your Java classes:

```
javac -g Foo.java
```

if you have just a single file (containing a static void main()) than you can simply run it with:

```
java path/to/your/compiled_class_file [<command line args>, ...]
```

Note: Run the command above without .class extension. i.e.

```
java Foo
```

if you want to generate a jar file from your compiled .class files run:

```
jar cf jar-file input-file(s)
```

However, I would recommend you to use a IDE that compiles, packs and runs your code for you automatically with one click. i.e. [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/)

Answer (score 0):

If your class is not into a package and is compiled as java.class in C:\TurboC4\TC\:

```
cd C:\TurboC4\TC\
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\bin java
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to run your single java class as a command line program, then the answer is in [This question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879679/running-java-program-from-command-line)

Example:

```
java my.class.HelloWorld
```

If you have compiled an entire java project into a JAR file, check [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780678/run-class-in-jar-file) for the answer.

Example:

```
java -cp c:\location_of_jar\myjar.jar com.mypackage.myClass
```