# How to run a java program in command line?

Tags: java

Here is the thing: I am trying to run the example program in the joda-time project.
The start of the Examples.java file looks like this:

```
package org.joda.example.time;

import java.util.Locale;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Instant;

/**
 * Example code demonstrating how to use Joda-Time.
 *
 * @author Stephen Colebourne
 */
public class Examples {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
        new Examples().run();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And all the classes for compiling this Example.java is in a joda-time-2.3.jar.
I can successfully compile this program by using

```
    javac -cp somewhere/joda-time-2.3.jar Example.java
```

And it generate an Example.class, but I jut cannot execute that.
So far I have tried:

```
java Examples
java -cp somewhere/joda-time-2.3.jar Examples
java -cp somewhere/joda-time-2.3.jar org.joda.example.time.Examples
```

But they all generate this kind of errors:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.joda.example.time.Example

Error: Could not find or load main class Examples

And I've tried both in the org/joda/example/time folder and the parent folder of org

Anyone can give an instruction on how to execute that? Really appreciate it!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9879679/running-java-program-from-command-line?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify your classpath parameter, so it should include directory where Example.class was generated.

In case of out/org/joda/example/time/Example.class you need to use

```
java -cp somewhere/jodata-time-2.3.jar:out org.joda.example.time.Example
```

Comment: Yeah I should addthe :out option. Thanks!

Comment: You also forgot to mention that `Examples` belongs to a `package`, so you need to use the fully qualified name ;)

Answer (score 3):

> Error: Could not find or load main class org.joda.example.time.Example

```
public class Examples {
```

Name of your class is `Examples` not `Example`

**EDIT**

*Sorry for late reply...*

To execute specific Java program you need to bring control to root directory so if your class is in `abc/newdir/Examples.java` you need to use `cd` command (in windows) to lead control to root directory and than compile or you can defeneitly go for the suggestion of *kogut*.

```
C:/abc/newdir>java -cp somewhere/joda-time-2.3.jar Examples
```

Comment: sorry it is a typo here. I actually used Examples. already edited that, thanks!