# Class-Path in jar file with combined libraries

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I am trying to create a jar file that is "self contained" concerning the libraries it needs.

Therefore, I created the following ant file:

```
<project name="srv" default="prod">
    <target name="prod">
        <jar destfile="build/ServerApplication.jar" basedir="bin/">
            <restrict>
             <name name="**/*.class"/>
             <archives>
               <zips>
                 <fileset dir="lib/" includes="**/*.jar"/>
               </zips>
             </archives>
            </restrict>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="." />
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="my.package.ServerApplication" />
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

But, when I try to launch the application using

```
> java -jar ServerApplication.jar
```

I get an error

> No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?user=root&password=

I reckon  this is because the `com.mysql.jdbc` package inside the jar can't be found. Why is this? When I set the *Class-Path* to `.`, shouldn't the jar be able to find all classes inside that jar?

I opened the jar in a decompiler, and all the classes are where they need to be, see here:

[image: Decompiled JAR]

What is going wrong here? My MANIFEST looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
Created-By: 1.7.0_07-b10 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: my.package.ServerApplication
Class-Path: .
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Eclipse: How to build an executable jar with external jar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must explicitly write the names of the jars if you want them included separated by spaces.  Otherwise I would recommend simply launching your jar and providing the class path as a parameter manually:

```
java -cp . -jar ServerApplication.jar
```

[See here for more information.](http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t130090-jar-files-and-manifest-class-path.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should avoid setting classpath at all, and since you are packaging everything in uber-jar - it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try the excellent eclipse plugin which is [fatjar](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/).
It had used it many times for including all dependencies of Java Swing based applications.