# NoClassDefFoundError after updating to Java 7

Tags: java, log4j, noclassdeffounderror

I'm getting the NoClassDefFoundError after executing my project's JAR file.
Debugging with Eclipse works fine, but I get this error whenever I use the windows command `java -jar myproject.jar` since I installed JDK 1.7.

It was working fine using Java 1.6.

Here's the error log :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
at program.Main.main(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 1 more
```

I googled about that but couldn't find the right solution.

What I already did :
-uninstall Java 1.7, install 1.6 instead
-check the classpath
-try on an other computer (after uninstalling Java 1.7 from it)
-create an empty project with one reference to the log4j library => same problem

And here's the classpath file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath> 
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/> 
<classpathentry kind="con"path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.6"/>
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/RXTXcomm.jar"/> 
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar"/> 
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/> 
</classpath>
```

Do you have any idea what else I should do?

Thanks,

Nils

EDIT : if I export the project as an "runnable JAR" instead of a simple "JAR", the program starts but fail to use another library I'm using (RxtxComm). Here's the log I get:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no rxtxSerial in java.library.path thrown while loading gnu.io.RXTXCommDriver
```

EDIT2: I finally resolved the last problem by putting the rxtxSerial.dll in the Windows/system32 folder.
But still, I don't understand why it doesn't work anymore if I export my project as a JAR file and why I need to use the dll file now.

Comment: have you seen this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar ?

Comment: Exporting it as a runnable JAR file instead of a simple JAR file seams to be working. I get another error, but the program starts and prints stuff on the screen.

Comment: I got it working with a runnable JAR. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure log4j's jar is in the classpath when running your jar file? Check that either:

- you have a CLASSPATH system variable which contains, amongst others, the folder wher log4j's jar is located
- you pass that log4j jar folder as an argument when launching the jar

  java -jar yourJar.jar -classpath c:\myLog4JJarFolder

UPDATE:

As per  Andrew Thompson's comment using the -jar argument will make your -classpath argument useless (it will be ignored). To be able to specify the classpath at the command line you have to also use the fully qualified name of your main class as a launch argument:

```
java -classpath "c:\dir1;c:\dir2" package.subPackage.MainClass
```

Comment: `java -jar yourJar.jar -classpath c:\myLog4JJarFolder`  The `-classpath` option is ignored if `-jar` is specified.

Comment: Doh, you're right, I'll update my anwer but also leave the original for other geniuses like me.

Comment: I did as you said. I went into the project's bin folder and launched the class : 
java -classpath "C:\Documents and Settings\Nils\workspace\Transcodeur2.1\src>java -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\lib\log4j-1.2.15.jar" fr.sncf.transcodeur.Main  
but i get this :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: fr/sncf/transcodeur/Main
I also tried adding the ".class" file extension (.. .Main.class), it didn't change a thing.
Btw, I'm not very comfortable using the console (that's what you get working with an IDE..!), so I might have misunderstood you.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above, a few things that I would check:

- Ensure that you have packaged all of your resources in the executable JAR.  Extract your jar and take a look just to make sure.
- Add the jar to the classpath:

  java -cp [jar here] main.java

Comment: I checked the JAR file, everything is in there ("lib" folder with all the librairies + .class files).
By executing the java -cp command, I get the error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Transcodeur2/1\src\fr\sncf\transcodeur\Main/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Transcodeur2.1\src\fr\sncf\transcodeur\Main.java
The path should be right, since I copy/pasted it from the windows explorer

Comment: I need two things. 1:  The present working directory you are running the java command from and 2:  the command you are typine (e.g. java -cp /src/main/lib/myjar.jar main.java