# Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout - While Runnig JAR from Command Prompt

Tags: java, command-line, jar, log4j

I'm trying run an jar file from command prompt. I am continually get the above error for all the below combinations i tried.

```
java -jar Mater.jar
java -cp ".:log4j-1.2.16.jar" -jar Mater.jar
java -cp log4j-1.2.16.jar -jar Mater.jar
```

I extracted log4j-1.2.16.jar to see if Layout was in the jar I'm referencing and it is there.

I have created the jar by using eclipse IDE "Export jar Option" and here is my manifest file.

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: TestController

Class-Path: apache-mime4j-0.6.jar bsh-1.3.0.jar cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar commons-beanutils-1.8.0.jar commons-codec-1.6.jar 

Class-Path: commons-collections-3.2.1.jar commons-exec-1.1.jar commons-io-2.0.1.jar commons-jxpath-1.3.jar commons-logging-1.1.1.jar 

Class-Path: cssparser-0.9.5.jar derbyclient.jar dom4j-1.1.jar eclipselink-2.0.0.jar flash-selenium.jar guava-12.0.jar hamcrest-core-1.1.jar 

Class-Path: htmlunit-2.9.jar htmlunit-core-js-2.9.jar httpclient-4.1.3.jar httpcore-4.1.3.jar httpmime-4.1.3.jar ini4j-0.5.2.jar 

Class-Path: javax.persistence-2.0.0.jar jcommander-1.13.jar jna-3.4.0.jar jna-platform-3.4.0.jar 

Class-Path: json-20080701.jar junit-dep-4.10.jar logging-selenium-1.2.jar mail.jar mysql-connector-java-5.0.7-bin(2).jar 

Class-Path: nekohtml-1.9.15.jar netty-3.2.7.Final.jar operadriver-0.14.jar 
poi-3.6-20091214.jar poi-ooxml-3.6-20091214.jar poi-ooxml-schemas-3.6-20091214.jar 

Class-Path: protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar sac-1.3.jar saxon-8.7.jar SaxonLiaison.jar selenium-java-2.25.0.jar selenium-java-2.25.0-srcs.jar 

Class-Path: selenium-java-client-driver.jar selenium-java-client-driver-sources.jar selenium-java-client-driver-tests.jar 

Class-Path: selenium-java-client-driver-test-sources.jar selenium-server.jar selenium-server-coreless.jar 

Class-Path: selenium-server-sources.jar serializer-2.7.1.jar testng.jar testng-6.0.1-nobsh-noguice.jar testng-xslt-maven-plugin-test-0.0.jar 

Class-Path: validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar webbit-0.4.8-SNAPSHOT.jar xalan-2.7.1.jar xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar xml-apis-1.3.04.jar xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar log4j-1.2.8.jar
```

I have cross checked if the classpath is set correctly in the jar using

**jar tf Mater.jar**

and it is displaying all the files inside jar on the command prompt correctly..

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I'm not sure but IIRC using `-jar` option ignores `-cp`. You probably need to set your classpath in jar's manifest file.

Comment: @Adam i have set the classpath in manifest file as i mentioned above and more over when i view the jar contents on command prompt all the jars,classfiles e.t.c are displayed correctly...

Comment: are you sure all the referenced jars are in the same directory as Mater.jar?

Comment: yes all are in the lib folder of project Mater

Comment: the paths in manifest are relative to the main jar (Mater.jar), so you need to change it so that they have correct relative path (eg. Class-Path: lib/protobuf-java-2.4.1.jar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem, with the same NoClassDefFoundError, in here : [NoClassDefFoundError after updating to Java 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371014/noclassdeffounderror-after-updating-to-java-7)

I can't explain why, but the only working solution I found was to export as a runnable JAR with Eclipse