# Java application does not work properly outside IDE

Tags: java, intellij-idea, shared-libraries

When I run it with IntelliJ Idea - it works completely right. When I run app.jar file from output - everything works good too, but one feature, which is supported by supportLib.jar. I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/plugin/dom/exception/InvalidAccessException` when use it.
The structure of the output is:

```
| D:\myprogram\

  |
  ---> app.jar 
  |
  ---> lib\  
        |
        ---> supportLib.jar
        ---> anotherSupportLib.jar
```

The ClassPath is: `lib/supportLib.jar lib/anotherSupportLib.jar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sun.plugin.dom.exception.InvalidAccessException` resides in `$JRE_HOME/lib/plugin.jar`, so you need to add `$JRE_HOME/lib/plugin.jar` to your classpath. I suppose that IntelliJ adds this automatically, but it is not automatically loaded by the Java runtime (unlike rt.jar).

---

Based on the feedback from the comments, the application should be started like this:

```
java -classpath "c:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/plugin.jar;app.jar;lib/supportLib1.jar;lib/supportLib2.jar;lib/supportLib3.jar" namespace.forms.MainForm
```

Comment: META-INF\MANIFEST.MF in output jar doesn't have `$JRE_HOME/lib/plugin.jar`. I added it this way: `$JRE_HOME/lib/plugin.jar lib/supportLib.jar lib/anotherSupportLib.jar`, it did not help. Did I added this part correctly?

Comment: You can not use variables in the Manifest file - the classpath in the Manifest is a relative path. Can you simply try to run your application with "java -classpath your_JRE_directory/lib/plugin.jar ...", to make sure that this is actually the issue?

Comment: I run my application with `java -classpath c:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/plugin.jar .;app.jar;lib/supportLib1.jar;lib/supportLib2.jar;lib/supportLib3.jar namespace.forms.MainForm` and give an error: Could not find or load main class Files.Java.jre7.lib.plugin.jar.
Without `$JRE_HOME/lib/plugin.jar` app runs, but necessary functionality does not work. Am I doing smth wrong?

Comment: You have spaces in your path - you need to quote them. Also, there is a bogus dot in your classpath - you should not need that. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Earned!! But what to do in order to run the executable JAR itself? It still has a manifest file inside with format:
`Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: lib/supportLib1.jar lib/supportLib2.jar lib/supportLib3.jar
Main-Class: namespace.forms.MainForm`

Comment: See [How to build an executable jar with external jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar). Technically, you have two options: either copy the plugin.jar file into your lib subdirectoy and add `lib/plugin.jar` to your manifest's `Class-Path`, or repackage plugin.jar so that its classes are included in your app.jar file. The latter could also be a good idea for your support libs, if you really want to have a complete self-containing runnable jar file.

Answer (score 2):

IDEA usually adds absolute path:

```
 -classpath D:\myprogram\lib\supportLib.jar;D:\myprogram\lib\anotherSupportLib.jar
```

Try to run your jar with this synthax.

Comment: I've tried with `java -classpath c:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/plugin.jar .;app.jar;lib/supportLib1.jar;lib/supportLib2.jar;lib/supportLib3.jar namespace.forms.MainForm`. But the problematic option still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

On windows machine this needs to be with semicolon `lib/supportLib.jar;lib/anotherSupportLib.jar`.

Comment: The application has stopped running

Comment: Excuse me! The application runs with `java -classpath c:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/plugin.jar .;app.jar;lib/supportLib1.jar;lib/supportLib2.jar;lib/supportLib3.jar namespace.forms.MainForm`. But the problematic option still doesn't work...