# how could I include external library in my export project archive

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to export my project to archive file by using eclipse. However, as I included an external library, db4o lb so that my project cannot run unit test on the other computer. So I wonder how could I export my project to archive file that could include the external library in it so that people who import my project could just run the unit test without first change the build-in config. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: what is the error you see when you run it on another computer

Comment: just import error, the external library is not found

Comment: set your library at the same folder as your jar file

Answer (score 0):

just take a look at maven.

You can otherwise put your project and associated dependency on a version manager (SVN, Git, etc..) and tell other people to checkout it from there.

Google code is a good solution if you don't want to set up your own

Answer (score 0):

You can create a runnable jar in Eclipse -- there is an option to package required libraries to the generated jar. For this, you need to have a run configuration, i.e. at least one of your classes should contain a main method. The jar can be referenced from projects just like non-runnable jars.

Alternatively, these are ways to do it
using Maven:
[Including dependencies in a jar with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729054/including-dependencies-in-a-jar-with-maven)

and using Ant (Lucas Pottersky's answer):
[Eclipse: How to build an executable jar with external jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar)