# Do I need to manually enter class names of classes in a .jar-file?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I'm trying to make a .jar file out of a java project I wrote in Eclipse and I'm following [this](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/85application/jar/jar.html) tutorial to get it done. I went to my 'workspace' directory and created the .mf file outside my src folder and opened a cmd window on the same level as the .mf file. I started the command `jar cmf mf-file.mf jartest.mf Class1.class Class2.class . . .` but I have like 40 classes! Is this really the way to make a double-click runnable program to use??

Comment: Have you tried using eclipse tools to create Jar file `File` -> `Export..` -> `jar` or `runnable jar`)?

Comment: `jar cmf mf-file.mf jartest.mf *.class`? You should not put classes in the default package.

Comment: I would use Ant if i wanted to build a jar without an IDE. Check out [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ant/ant_creating_jar_files.htm). Here's [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar) about how to do it with Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, right-click on your project and select `Export`.  Under `Java` select `Runnable JAR file` and go from there.

Comment: Alright.. Well that was really quick and painless. Thank you, haha :-)