# Ask user to set parameters at Install time and save them for a Java application

Tags: java

I want to create an installable Java application and allow the user to set some values at install time.  I would like those values to be saved in a file in the installation directory.

Can anyone recommend a simple way to do that? I'd like the solution to be free if possible.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question came to me in a review queue for help and improvement.  I've edited the language a bit and made the title more informative for any future visitors.  You can see the edits I made by [clicking on the revisions link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29747082/revisions). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create [Runnable JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar) file with swing GUI screen with the input box and GUI interface which save setting at back-end in file.
2. Check on every starting that you have settled up everything or not ?

**If yes then**

3. Start application

**If no then**

4. Settle up everything with GUI.

Comment: Thanks , just the first time . so in GUI with swing I can make the panel to show only the first time ? because I don't want to user modify the parametres after

Comment: Yes @YoussefSaih check for setting file in installation directory at every time when program starts and check for setting file.