# Java export with external libraries and Ant errors

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

So i have an application ready to turn into a runnable java jar.

I followed [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20831666/1212674)

My build.xml looks like this. EDIT property line has been added

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project default="create_run_jar" name="Create Runnable Jar for Project PaintingAPicture">
    <!--this file was created by Eclipse Runnable JAR Export Wizard-->
    <!--ANT 1.7 is required                                        -->
    <target name="jar">
    <property name="java.library.path" value="C:/opencv/build/java/x64" />

        <jar destfile="C:/Users/Robert/Desktop/Expo/Project.jar" filesetmanifest="mergewithoutmain">
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="paintPic.ThreadMaster"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="."/>
            </manifest>
            <fileset dir="C:/Users/Robert/Documents/GitHub/Project/PaintingAPicture/bin"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/opencv/build/java/opencv-2411.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/mfz-rxtx-2.2-20081207-win-x64/RXTXcomm.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/lib/arduino-core.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/lib/ecj.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/lib/jna.jar"/>
            <zipfileset excludes="META-INF/*.SF" src="C:/Program Files (x86)/Arduino/lib/pde.jar"/>
        </jar>
    </target>
</project>
```

ant jar, works fine and it buils successfully.

But when i run the jar with

```
java -j Project.jar
```

I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java2411 in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at paintPic.ThreadMaster.main(ThreadMaster.java:24)
```

I aim to export this Jar to another device, I am just not sure why it won't run.

Answer (score 0):

Try to start it as

```
java -jar Project.jar -Djava.library.path=C:/opencv/build/java/x64
```

Comment: Sadly still getting the same error, it is strange because everything runs fine in Eclipse.