# Build a jar in eclipse with jdbc driver

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I had developped a program in Java with eclipse using a MariaDb database .

I had imported the jdbc driver jar file of mariadb using `build classpath`

When I run the program in Eclipse, it's works fine.

But when i build the jar and run the program using the line command `java -jar <my program path>` I got this error :

> Not suitable driver found for jdbc:mariadb

What does I missed ?

**EDIT : Problem resolve thanks to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar)**

Comment: Oh thanks you, I resolve the problem thanks to the other question.