# Exporting java file with external JAR library

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

Is there a way to export java project with external jar library as a single file, so it can run on other machines from command line (no gui).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse: How to build an executable jar with external jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502960/eclipse-how-to-build-an-executable-jar-with-external-jar)

Comment: @IgorQuirino Given this question makes no reference to Eclipse, that question is not a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 0):

Look up how to do a "Fat Jar". A "Fat Jar" has all of the dependencies inside of the jar.